# Excel formula - Average of vlookup results for every other field in a source field

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm writing an organization sheet for a fledgling esports team, and my goal here is to calculate the average in-game rank of the players on my team.

Cell `F2` and every *other* row in column `F` has a rank identifier, like "S3" or "G1" (for ranks silver 3 or gold 1).

I have another sheet which contains numerical mappings between these rank identifiers (I1 is 1, I2 is 2, etc.)

So, for every other row in this range (`F2:F100`), I need to get the identifier, convert it to its numerical form by way of a `VLOOKUP` against the `Lookups` sheet, do a `FLOOR(AVERAGE()` of the result,  and convert that number back to a textual form by reversing the `VLOOKUP`.

I've got a couple of steps done already, but I'm not sure how to average across the results of a previous formula like this.

To get the numerical version of a rank from its textual version, the formula is:

`=VLOOKUP(F2, Lookups!A2:B29,2, FALSE)`

What I don't know is:

- How to do a cell reference that omits every other cell
- How to average across a large amount of VLOOKUP results

## Data example

Main sheet

[image: Main spreadsheet]

Lookup table

[image: Lookups spreadsheet]

Each set of two columns represents a single player, with that player's rank stored on the F row of the even numbered column. From the lookup sheet, we can see that S3 represents a numerical score of 10. The next player's G2 would be a score of 15, and so forth.

Once I have a sum of these numbers, I take the average, giving me an average score for the team. Back to the lookup table, this is done in reverse of the previous operation, and gives me a single rank that corresponds to the average score of every player listed on the sheet.

Taking the three players on the sheet currently, I would take S3, G2, and NA. This gives me a score of 10, 15, and 10,. The average of these is 11 (rounded down) which corresponds back to a rank of S2 using the lookup table. The cell containing this hypothetical formula would say "S2".

Comment: `MOD(ROW($2:$100), 2)=0` can be used as a boolean qualifier for every second row in an array-type formula but I really don't understand your narrative. Maybe add sample data for both sheets together with expected results.

Comment: @Jeeped I've updated the question with some more info. I hope that helps.

Comment: Will F3, F5, F7, etc remain blank? If not, will they be populated with anything that could provide a false positive match to Lookups!A2:A29?

Comment: They will. I've grayed out the field to show that nothing should be entered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *Will F3, F5, F7, etc remain blank?*
>  A: They will. I've grayed out the field to show that nothing should be entered there.

The easiest thing to do would be to use these blank cells to hold the numeric values for the individual ranks. You can then average F2:F101 and only the true numbers will be considered. The numbers can be hidden from display using the cell number format `;;;`. This displays a blank cell for anything typed or returned from a formula while retaining the raw value.

If you don't want to copy and paste 50 times, run this short sub procedure after adjusting the name of the Main worksheet in the first code line.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateLookups()

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "F"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)  '<~~ see footnote
                With .Offset(1, 0)

                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(r[-1]c, lookups!r2c1:r29c2, 2, false)"
                    .NumberFormat = ";;;"

                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Now you can use one of the following to achieve an average of the lookup values.

```
=average(F2:F100)
=average(F:F)
```

If you don't want to repurpose those blank cells, a 'helper column' is a viable alternative. I tested the blank method against the helper column method and the results were identical.

---

¹ <sub>If the existing ranks are returned by formula and not typed in, then **xlCellTypeConstants** should be replaced by **xlCellTypeFormulas**.</sub>

Comment: This ended up being what I did. Formatting those other cells to the hidden value (a neat trick I didn't know about!) makes this a lot easier than some monster formula, and then as you say, I can just average those and do a normal lookup. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve the first lookup, where you need a value on every other row, by placing the vlookup inside an iferror formula that just returns blank text when it can't find a result:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,Lookups!A2:B29,2,0),"")
```

Next, you can just use the average formula, inside of a rounddown formula to truncate the decimals. The average formula will simply ignore the blank rows.

Last, a vlookup formula won't work to grab the "Rank" from this average because it always starts at the left, and moves right - where you need to look at the right, and move left. For this, I use an Index/Match combo:

```
=INDEX(Lookups!A2:B29,MATCH(E11,Lookups!B2:B29,1),1)
```

For the match portion, I used a "1" parameter so that it would find the closest value without going over, assuming that it might not be an exact match. Check out the index and match formula descriptions inside of excel for more info and options.

I built this in a sample sheet that shows the formulas written out. Hope this helps: [Sample solution with formula examples shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVNTi.png)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the explanation and examples, and welcome to SU!

This is so *extremely* close to what I'm looking for, but it looks like it requires bringing in the scores adjacent to each rank on the player sheet. Is there a way to do this in a single formula, getting the average for *all* players and outputting a single rank without adding more fields to the sheet than are shown in the question? I'm also open to redesigning this sheet if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @MikeyT.K. :) How many rows on you’re main spreadsheet do you have? Are they static, or will they grow / shrink over time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get the average of even numbered rows, use the following formula:

```
=IF(ROW()/2 = ROUND(ROW()/2,0),VLOOKUP(A1,H$1:I$5,2,FALSE),"")
```

Else use:

```
=IF(ROW()/2 <> ROUND(ROW()/2,0),VLOOKUP(A1,H$1:I$5,2,FALSE),"")
```

Then use `=AVERAGE(G1:G5)` to get the average